# How to find path to a node in a Haskell Data.Tree

Tags: haskell, tree

Given a tree in Haskell (represented by a `Data.Tree`), how could I find the path to a node?

e.g.

```hs
import Data.Tree

tree = Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 []], Node 4 []]
```

Which forms a tree that looks like:

```
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  `- 3
|
`- 4
```

How could I make a function `pathToNode` such that:

```
pathToNode 0 tree => []
pathToNode 1 tree => [1]
pathToNode 2 tree => [1, 2]
pathToNode 3 tree => [1, 2, 3]
pathToNode 4 tree => [1, 4]
```

In my particular case, any given value will appear only once in the tree, so a solution that returns the *a* path to a value is acceptable.

So far my best answer is this:

```hs
pathToNode :: (Eq a) => a -> Tree a -> [a]
pathToNode x (Node y ys) | x == y    = [x]
                         | otherwise = case concatMap (pathToNode x) ys of
                                         [] -> []
                                         path -> y:path
```

Is there a more succinct way of writing this? Is it possible to take advantage of `Data.Foldable` or `Data.Traversable` to avoid writing my own traverse logic?

Comment: András Kovács's answer made me aware that the question is ambiguous about what I want to happen when a value appears more than once in a tree. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `Traversable` and `Foldable` instances can't be used here, since they don't provide enough contextual information to maintain a path (e. g. when traversing in the `State` monad). They both visit each element of the tree once in some order, so you can't know whether some previously visited value belongs to a parent or sibling node of the current node.

I think the following function is succinct enough:

```
pathsToNode :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> [[a]]
pathsToNode x (Node y ns) = [[x] | x == y] ++ map (y:) (pathsToNode x =<< ns)
```

It lists the paths to all copies of `x`, but you can always just lazily take the first found path if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks. This took me a while to understand, mostly because I'm not very familiar with exploiting the monadic nature of lists.  If I understand correctly, 1pathsToNode x =<< ns` is equivalent to `concatMap (pathsToNode x) ns`. I still don't quite grok how the first list comprehension desugars.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard and http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension provide the missing pieces for understanding how `[[x] | x == y]` works.

Answer (score 5):

There exists a generalization of the concept of a fold called a [catamorphism](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Catamorphisms). In the same way that a fold lets you "consume" a list without explicit recursion, a catamorphism lets you "consume" a tree or other datatype without explicit recursion and in a bottom-up manner, starting from the leaves. Unlike a regular fold, it will be aware of the structure of the tree.

The [`cata`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.0/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#g:3) function can be found in module [`Data.Functor.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.0/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) (not `Data.Foldable`!) of package [`recursion-schemes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes). Unfortunately, it doesn't work with `Data.Tree` as such, you'll have to define an equivalent datatype in an indirect, two-step fashion:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable

data Node a b = Node a [b] deriving (Functor,Eq)

type Tree a = Fix (Node a)

tree :: Tree Int
tree = Fix (Node 1 [ Fix ( Node 2 [ Fix (Node 3 []) ]), 
                     Fix ( Node 4 [] ) ])
```

Using `cata`, we can construct a list of all the paths to all values in the tree. Notice the lack of explicit recursion:

```
paths :: Tree a -> [(a,[a])]
paths = cata algebra  
    where
    algebra :: Node a [(a,[a])] -> [(a,[a])]
    algebra (Node a as) = (a,[a]) : map (\(i,is)->(i,a:is)) (concat as)
```

And from that function, we can define pathToNode:

```
pathToNode :: (Eq a) => a -> Tree a -> [a]
pathToNode a = snd . head . filter ((==a).fst) . paths
```

This solution is not more succint I'm afraid, but catamorphims are a useful tool to have in your belt.